# Finding the parameters of a function via curve fit

Tags: optimization, python, scipy, approximation, curve-fitting

I'm trying to estimate the parameters (v, n, k) defined in `fit_func`. I tried the default least squares fit but I couldn't find the parameters successfully.

```
def fit_func(x, v, n, k):
    return v * x ** n / (k ** n + x ** n)

x = [2.5,         2.71317829,  4.08,        4.18604651,  5.19379845,  6.92,
 7.98449612,  8.94,        9.92248062,  9.94,       12.36,       13.48837209]
y = [0.16054661, 0.14643943, 0.11639118, 0.11796543, 0.15609638, 0.29527088,
 0.40774818, 0.51331307, 0.6163489,  0.61807529, 0.78372639, 0.78643515]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_func, x, y)
print(popt)
plt.plot(x, y, '*')
plt.plot(x, fit_func(x, *popt), 'r')
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
    raise RuntimeError("Optimal parameters not found: " + errmsg)
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.
```

I'm not sure if I have selected the right method.
Suggestions on alternate methods that I could use to estimate the parameters will be really helpful.

Cross-posted: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916776/finding-the-parameters-of-a-function-via-curve-fit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you transform your formula and data to the reciprocals, you get
$$
\frac1y=\frac1v\left(\frac{k^n}{x^n}+1\right)
$$
or
$$
y^{-1}=Ax^{-n}+B
$$
The graph of this should be an $n$th power parabola elevated by some constant.

Now plotting the data in this fashion gives

[image]

which in the first 3 data points does not fit the expected behavior. Leaving these 3 points out

```python
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_func, x[3:], y[3:], p0 = [1,3,20])
```

results in a fit with parameters

```
1.030581640553569 3.1928649383817267 8.923440277503085
```

and plot

[image]

Comment: Wonderful explanation! I love it:) Could you  please confirm the last value in `popt`? I get `[1.03058199 3.19286183 8.92344026]` . Thanks so much

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I used the wrong code variant to modify. I removed the $n$th power from $k$ to reduce complexity, without any change in the success or failure of the fit. // The initial guess used is rather fortunate, especially in the value of the power $n$ large deviations lead to negative exponents in the search, and a useless result.